# Register form Error Correction in PHP - Best solution?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, web, switch-statement

I'm looking for as simple approach to correcting errors such as non-matching passwords and people inserting blank data into a form in HTML.

I want to use PHP to throw me back an error when this happens, I was considering using if statements but realised it would not show more than one error if it happens.

Here is an example of what I *was* doing, keeping in mind $firstname's input is from POST:

```
if ($firstname == "")
{
$_SESSION['nofirstname'] = 1;
header('Location: register.php');
}
```

In register.php it picks up this, and warns the user that he has entered no first name. This is cool but won't display additional errors if there are any. I'm guessing switches and arrays are the way forward but I don't really understand how to add a entry to an array.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: is that your full code and what have you tried?

Comment: Instead of redirecting inside your conditional statement, first check all of your "exceptions" and set those session variables accordingly. Then, when you've checked everything, call header.

Comment: You mention and I quote `"how to add a entry to an array"`; you want to `add` an entry to an `array`, where's your array to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
....
    $_SESSION['flag']=false;
    if ($firstname == "")
    {
    $_SESSION['nofirstname'] = 1;$_SESSION['flag']=true;
    }
    if ($lastnamee == "")
    {
    $_SESSION['nolastname'] = 1;$_SESSION['flag']=true;
    }
    ...

    header('Location: register.php');
```

in register.php

```
session_start();
...
    if ($_SESSION['flag']==true){
       if ($_SESSION['nofirstname']==1) {///message}
       if ($_SESSION['nolastname']==1) {///message}
       ...
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to supply an `answer`, may as well `Go for the GOLD` and add `session_start();` to the start of your code. ;-)

Comment: I doubt it. The OP hasn't shown up in interacting with the ones who've worked hard to provide him with answers/suggestions. This one is `Dead in the Water` as it were, and is the second time where he does not let anyone know he's still alive and hasn't accepted any answers. `Fool me once "shame on HIM". Fool me twice "shame on ME".` I'm upvoting everyone who supplied an answer and downvoting his question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested if, e.g;

```
<?php
    if($firstcond){
        if($secondcond){

        }else{
             $_SESSION['error'] = 'Second Condition not met!';
             header('Location: register.php');
             //error
        }
    }else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'First Condition not met!';
        header('Location: register.php');
        //error
    }
?>
```

This means that in order for `$secondcond` to be validated, `$firstcond` must pass whatever checks you perform on it first :)

Comment: You left out `session_start();` also.

Comment: @Fred I assumed he already has started the session somewhere above, doesn't look like the code would be at the very top of the page?

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be the next line under opening `<?php`. You remember the old proverb about `assume`? Let's not ;-)

Comment: Yes but if he has opened/closed PHP tags before this he could have easily declared it there :) Is that the one with the donkey ;)?

Comment: Only if the donkey goes for the `carrot`. The sweeter the carrot, the sweeter the ride!

Comment: Plus, it's always best that the OP posts his full code as much as possible. Leaves the guesswork right out. I never paid attention in `mind-reading class` ;-)

Comment: Very true :) Not many people I know majored in `mind-reading` lol

Comment: Upvoted for the `effort`. Seems this question is `Dead in the Water`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    session_start();
    ob_start()

 if ($firstname == "")
    {
    $_SESSION['nofirstname'] = "Enter your name";
    header('Location: register.php');
    }
```

Redirect the page and display

```
echo isset($_SESSION['nofirstname'])?$_SESSION['nofirstname']:'';
```

Try this.

Comment: Upvoted for the `effort`. Seems this question is `Dead in the Water`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
session_start();

$errors = array();

if ($firstname == "")
{
    $errors['nofirstname'] = 1;
}
if ($lastname == "")
{
    $errors['nolastname'] = 1;
}

$run = 1;
foreach ($errors AS $key => $value)
{
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    $run = 0;
}

if (!$run)
    header('Location: register.php');
```

Comment: If you're going to use `$_SESSION`, you left out putting `session_start();` at the top. ;-)

Comment: Upvoted for the `effort`. Seems this question is `Dead in the Water`.